# Visual Studio skips build

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005, build

When I try to build my project I get the following message in the build window :

**========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========**

I tried rebuilding , then building again , but it doesn't help . Is there a way to view more detailed messages ? The "skipped" part doesn't give me any info on what's wrong . I am using Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition .

Comment: When nothing else helps, restarting Visual Studio can have surprising effects. Which suggests that among other things this could be caused by a VS bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine why visual studio might be skipping projects when building a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319772/how-to-determine-why-visual-studio-might-be-skipping-projects-when-building-a-so)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check with the configuration manager like CMS said and make sure that you have the right platform set. A lot of the time when you use something like the MS Application Blocks the default platform is set to Itanium.

Comment: And what it should be set to ?

Comment: depends on your machine but in most cases it would win32

Comment: Or else Any CPU like in CMS' screenshot

Comment: That was it ! I changed it to Win32 and the build started . Thanks !

Comment: Great, Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 12):

Check on your solution properties, then go to "Configuration Properties", and make sure that all the  projects that you want to build, have the build flag checked:

Answer (score 3):

Yet another reason why this could happen (as it happened to me):

When your VS installation is missing **x64 compiler toolchain**, and you're building for x64.

To solve this, find MSVS in `appwiz.cpl` ("Programs and Features"), click "Uninstall/Change", then go to the x64 toolchain checkbox under C++ and check it.

Answer (score 1):

This recently happened to me when I tried to compile a project that was apparently orphaned from it's parent solution.

When I finally did get it to compile, it wouldn't work because some library from another project was missing (that was supposed to be part of the solution to get a successful build).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I remember cursing at that one once? Just guessing from my awful memory, but perhaps the output directory path doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution *.sln file to be the problem.
Reverted back to a previous version and it fixed the problem.
Often the project references a project that is the actual offender, so try and build up the reference list to see where the problem is.

Answer (score -3):

I generally run into that when the PC is low on resources (RAM), after closing things the build runs fine.