# CMAKE build different platform in one solution

Tags: visual-studio, build, cmake, vcxproj

**Hello.**

From cmake i'm generate visual studio(2013) solution with x64 generator, and *include_external_msproject* which have only win32 platform.

When i'm open solution, by default, my win32 solution excluded from build(Field Build don't checkmark).

Question, how i can set force build for win32 project from cmake?

For example:

```
include_external_msproject(splash ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/splash.vcxproj)
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNCWu.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add your CMake code doing the `include_external_msproject()`? See [mcve]. I'm asking because normally the external projects are included in the default build.  Generally speaking you can control this with e.g. `set_target_properties(MyExtProject PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD 0)`.

Comment: ok, i'm editing my question.
set_target_properties(splash PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD 0) doesn't help

Comment: Can you give the solution described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859576/c-sharp-projects-in-cmake-made-vs2010-solution-must-be-unloaded-reloaded-to-avoi) a try?

Comment: Thx your link helped.
Need add parammetrs PLATFORM Win32 on include function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function have parametrs PLATFORM, which set default platform.
Be warning your external project, must have same number of configuration and platform. Exmaple: If your main solution have MinSizeRel Win32, your external project must have too.

```
include_external_msproject(splash ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/splash.vcxproj PLATFORM Win32)
```