# Current solution contains incorrect configuration mappings

Tags: visual-studio

I get this error in VS:

> Current solution contains incorrect configuration mappings. It may
> cause projects to not work correctly. Open the Configuration Manager
> to fix them.

I then open Configuration Manager, and click on Close and the error goes away.

I can then see it made these changes to my .sln file:

[image]

Why were the original configuration mappings incorrect?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It's not uncommon that shared projects get included in the list of projects to build. Not sure it applies to all cases but clearing everything between:

```
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
```

and

```
EndGlobalSection
```

in the .sln file and then reloading the solution will at least solve those.

Comment: I removed GlobalSection, but Visual Studio added it back again directly with changes very similar to the OP.  The actual answer to the question is probably related to the configuration not being available in the project.

Comment: Cleaning lines as described in this asnwer helped. By the way, opening configuration manager does not helped.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to close all VS instances as I had another project open

Comment: Wow this worked for me when upgrading a Xamarin.Forms project to MAUI and having incorrect build configurations. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was because the .csproj file had the wrong profiles compared to the global profiles.

Ensure that the  tag has the correct value. You'll probably find in said project something like:

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
```

It should look like

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug_VSTS</Configuration>
```

Comment: I can't see any <configuration> in my .sln file.

Comment: @Amir978, that's because it's in the project file, not the solution.

Answer (score 3):

A colleague just had this message pop up, and it turned out it was because the sln file had been updated (automatically, by Visual Studio) to try and compile a Shared Project (which is nonsense)

Long story short, the fix was to edit the sln file and remove the references to the Shared Project, very similar to the last time Shared Projects caused me an issue as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319772/how-to-determine-why-visual-studio-might-be-skipping-projects-when-building-a-so/54041518#54041518)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem upgrading an old .NET Framework project to .NET 8. I was missing a `<Configurations>` property in the main property group of the project file, and VS couldn't cope with this being missing when I tried to fix things in the Configuration Manager. After clearing `ProjectConfigurationPlatforms` in the solution as per jool's answer, VS gained enough cope to create the `<Configurations>` property. Setting this property yourself in the csproj is enough to fix the problem without messing with the solution file, e.g. for the OP's configurations:

```
<Configurations>Debug;Release;Debug_VSTS;Release_VSTS</Configurations>
```

Comment: For reference, this also applies to platforms as well. It assumes `Any CPU` if the `Platforms` element is missing like it does with `Configurations` and "Debug;Release".
Additionally, VS won't allow you to add the configurations and platforms via the dialog to avoid clobbering any settings still in the project file

Answer (score -2):

In my case, it appears as a message bar on top of my code pages in VS, when I clicked on it, it opened the Build Configuration and as soon as I closed it, the message disappeared.

Comment: This will just map the projects to some default. It doesn't fix the problem and maps solution-level configurations to whatever defaults the IDE feels like.